# Distributions of groups of similar objects arranged linearly and circularly

Tags: combinatorics

The following question is from [this](http://books.google.co.in/books/about/Discrete_Mathematics_for_Computer_Scient.html?id=We5QAAAAMAAJ) textbook (Section 2.5, p. 185).

> 8.A child has blocks of $6$ different colors
>
> c) if the child selects $4$ blocks of each color, in how many ways can these $24$ blocks be arranged in a line ?

Answer: $$\frac{24!}{(4!)^6}$$

> d) In how many ways can the $24$ blocks be arranged in a circle ?

My attempt: Let the number of ways be $c$. Each circular arrangement gives rise to $x$ linear arrangements. Therefore, we have

$$ c * x = \frac{24!}{(4!)^6}$$

Is this approach correct ?

Answer (score 0):

I agree with your answer for $\left(a\right)$.

For $\left(b\right)$:

One circular arrangement (CA) translates to multiple linear
arrangements (LAs) as you suggested. For any given CA, this multiple
depends on the length of any pattern of balls repeated throughout
the CA.

Eg. If our colours are $A,B,C,D,E \mbox{ and } F$ then a CA with
$"ABCDEF"$ repeated $4$ times translates to $6$ LAs; fewer than a
more random CA.

Because there are $6$ colours, the length, $L$, of any such pattern
must be a multiple of $6$. Also it must divide $24$.

So $L \in \left\{6, 12, 24\right\}$.

Let $N_L$ be the number of CAs with a shortest repeated pattern of
length $L$.

$N_6 = 6!\qquad\mbox{(Number of arrangements of $6$ different
colours)}$

$N_{12} = \dfrac{12!}{\left(2!\right)^6} - 6!$

First term: same idea as in part $\left(a\right)$

Second term: don't count the CAs counted in $N_6$.

$N_{24} = \dfrac{24!}{\left(4!\right)^6} -
\dfrac{12!}{\left(2!\right)^6}$

Note that each CA is counted exactly once now.

Each CA counted in $N_L$ translates to $L$ LAs because you can start
at each position in the pattern to get a different LA.

So the number of CAs:
\begin{eqnarray*}
Ans &=& \dfrac{1}{6} N_6 + \dfrac{1}{12} N_{12} + \dfrac{1}{24}
N_{24}
\\
&=& \dfrac{1}{6} \left(6!\right) + \dfrac{1}{12}
\left(\dfrac{12!}{\left(2!\right)^6} - 6!\right) + \dfrac{1}{24}
\left(\dfrac{24!}{\left(4!\right)^6} -
\dfrac{12!}{\left(2!\right)^6}\right) \\
&=& 5! + \dfrac{11!}{2^6} - \dfrac{5!}{2} +
\dfrac{23!}{\left(4!\right)^6} - \dfrac{11!}{2^7} \\
&=&\dfrac{5!}{2} + \dfrac{11!}{2} + \dfrac{23!}{\left(4!\right)^6}
\end{eqnarray*}